# How to find the Salesforce patch version of a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, patch

Known issues such as this one [lightning:recordEditForm does not display fields from standard objects when in create mode](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BhOQAU) list the instances that the fix has been applied to e.g. CS11 or NA6. But I'm developing in a [scratch org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) where that naming pattern isn't used.

How can I find out the Salesforce patch status - e.g. "SPRING '18 PATCH 6.0" - of the scratch org I am working in?

**PS**

Just noticed that scratch orgs have an "Instance" of e.g. "CS11" in their Company Information. Wondering if that does or does not mean that the patch level is the same as for that instance?

Comment: This is not exclusive to scratch orgs. Developer, Sandbox and Production instances have the instance information on the company page. So I'd say that the patch level that applies to the scratch org is the same as that instance's. It just doesn't make sense not to have the same patch on an instance.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Agree and I'll assume that for now. Just looking for a definitive statement on the matter.